# org.springframework.web.servlet not found in maven

Tags: spring, dependencies

I am trying to download the org.springframework.web.servlet using maven dependency
but maven could not download it.i want to know is this dependency is there in maven or not

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.web.servlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

or spring has changed its dependency or can we use some alternate dependency for it.please suggest

Comment: Hey @Zoheb. Did this work out for you?

Answer (score 15):

The **package** org.springframework.web.servlet is contained in the **spring-webmvc** module. Use this dependency:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>`
```

**Update**: Since this post is quite old, please check for newer versions of the spring framework. Release 3.1.1.RELEASE is quite out-dated.